# Android: Reading a file using InputStream character by character

Tags: java, android, inputstream, android-context

Solved: The code I originally posted is fine, I just tried reading a txt file from a directory in assets without adding the directory's name in the "path" string under the false assumption "getAssets()" gets all assets from all subdirectories in assets.

I am making a game that uses cards with a name and description, the name and description are read from a .txt file in the assets folder. The method is made so it reads everything between '$' and '#' as the name, and '@' and '#' as the description. I wrote the original method in Eclipse (console application) and it worked like a charm. Then I transferred it to Android Studio, added context (since the method is in a class file) and AssetManager, etc and followed instructions from other similar stackoverflow questions but for some reason it just won't work.

Here is the code:

```
public void readFile(String p) throws IOException {

    // Path of the directory
    String path = new String(p);
    // AssetManager opens assets
    AssetManager am = con.getAssets();
    // Open file
    InputStream i_s = am.open(path);

    // StringBuilders store the text read for specific members
    StringBuilder _name = new StringBuilder("");  // Records name of card from file
    StringBuilder _desc = new StringBuilder("");  // Records description of card from file

    // "c" stores each character at a time
    char c;

    // Main loop that reads entire file
    while(i_s.available() > 0) { 
        c = (char) i_s.read();

        if(c=='$') {
            c = (char) i_s.read();  // Sends to next character so it doesn't save '$'
            while(c!='#')            // Loop saves everything between '$' and '#'
            {_name.append(c); c = (char) i_s.read();}
        }
        else if(c=='@') {
            c = (char) i_s.read();  // Sends to next character so it doesn't save '@'
            while(c!='#')            // Loop saves everything between '@' and '#'
            {_desc.append(c); c = (char) i_s.read();}
        }
    }
    i_s.close();

    // Sets read info into Class properties
    this.setName(_name);
    this.setDesc(_desc);

}
```

The method is in CardAction card,a subclass of Card. The set methods are in the Card class.

```
public void setName(StringBuilder sb) {
    this.name = sb.toString();
}
public void setDesc(StringBuilder sb) {
    this.desc = sb.toString();
}
```

Every time I test this (by calling the get methods for name and desc) it return empty strings. What am I doing wrong here?

Additional info: All the Card subclasses inherit the context "con" from Card superclass which passes the context from the main activity as a parameter in the Card constructor, so I am 100% sure Context and AssetManager are working fine.

Edit: Code that calls the readFile method from main activity

```
String str;
Turn t = new Turn(3, 40, t_o_d, names, true, 1, con);

// chooseFile returns String of randomly chosen file
// name from the assets folder (randomly "draw" card), works
str = t.chooseFile(1); 

CardAction ca = new CardAction(con); //Passes context as parameter for constructor
 try {ca.readFile(str);}
 catch(IOException e1) {}

 // cardName and cardDesc are TextViews I set just for testing the readFile method
 cardName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 cardDesc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 cardName.setText(ca.getName());
 cardDesc.setText(ca.getDesc());
```

Comment: Could you be mixing up the instances where these fields are set for other instances where they haven't been? It would help to either show the code that ties everything together, or to add logging of both the data and the owning instance (it, the "this") where you set and get values and see if that helps you figure it out yourself.

Comment: Added the code, I considered what you're saying before I made the original post, which is why I added "this" to everything to make sure there wouldn't be any confusion in the program. I'll admit, I'm still an amateur in this so I don't know 100% in which situations I should and shouldn't put "this" so I put it everywhere out of paranoia.

Comment: You should really have your catch block do an e1.printStackTrace() - right now it will just silently absorb errors, which tends to lead to *failures being unexplained...*  once you add that, look in the log and you may well have some exception related to the read attempt. As for excessive use of "this" - that won't generally help things or prevent mixups, as what "this" is depends entirely on where it occurs.

Comment: I know about the catch thing, this particular try-catch block is just to test the method and not going to be a part of the final program. I will do some reading on how to use "this" properly though, thanks for bringing my attention to that. 

Apart from the "this" thing, everything else about the method (the InputStream, the while loops, etc) is written how it should be?

Comment: No, your catch block is quite misguided - you really have to have noisy ones during development.  You can silence them for release if you want, but for right now having an empty catch block on your I/O code is the software equivalent of sticking your fingers in your ears and going on about how you can't tell what is wrong with your program.

Comment: Your solution belongs as an answer, not as an edit to your question.  But you obstinance  in maintaining the silent catch block is your more fundamental mistake - without that, you would have solved this immediately by seeing the exception.

Comment: I put System.out.println() in the catch block, thank you very much, I did not realize how useful that habit can be. I will immediately mend this and put the solution as an answer (I thought I should put it at the beginning of the question so no one would waste time reading the code looking for mistakes that aren't there)

Comment: Printing the stack trace of the exception is even more useful than just logging that there's been one, as it will point you right at the offending line of code.

Comment: I understand, the thing is that I have a void function that calls several other void functions (I'm obsessed with modularity) so I put System.out.println after each "complicated" part regardless of whether it has or hasn't a try-catch block. Thank you so much for the help, I'm just a college sophomore who started coding in Java like 3-4 months ago...

Answer (score 0):

Solved. the method is fine, what my problem was that I tried to open txt files located in their own folders in assets, so I just added another String parameter to the method (for the directory) and concatenated them (adding "/" between them).

Well, considering this was a solution for a completely other problem, I'm still glad this works so anyone struggling with reading files character by character can refer to the code I originally posted :)